# How do I display a ModalPopupExtender from another ModalPopupExtender and set which one has to be shown first?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a ModalPopUpExtender that contains a button that display a second ModalPopUpExtender . The problem is that when I show the second ModalPopUpExtender  it appears behind the first. Is it any way i can set that the second ModalPopUpExtender  was shown ahead of the fist one?

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManagerProfesiones" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAgenda" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar ID="DayPilotCalendar1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFD5" BorderColor="Black" CssClassPrefix="calendar_default" DayFontFamily="Tahoma" DayFontSize="15pt" DurationBarColor="Blue" EventBackColor="White" EventBorderColor="Black" EventClickHandling="PostBack" EventFontFamily="Tahoma" EventFontSize="8pt" EventHoverColor="Gainsboro" HourBorderColor="#EAD098" HourFontFamily="Tahoma" HourFontSize="16pt" HourHalfBorderColor="#F3E4B1" HourNameBackColor="#ECE9D8" HourNameBorderColor="#ACA899" HourWidth="100" HoverColor="#FFED95" NonBusinessBackColor="#FFF4BC" StartDate="2015-03-25" TimeFormat="Clock24Hours" CellHeight="40" HeaderHeight="40" OnEventClick="DayPilotCalendar1_EventClick" OnTimeRangeSelected="DayPilotCalendar1_TimeRangeSelected" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 375px; height: 501px; margin-right: 221px" Width="600px" TimeRangeSelectedHandling="PostBack" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modificarTurno_ModalPopupExtender"   runat="server" Enabled="True"  PopupControlID="PanelModificarTurno" DropShadow="false" BackgroundCssClass="FondoAplicacion" TargetControlID="lb">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"  runat="server" Enabled="True"  PopupControlID="panelClientes" DropShadow="false" BackgroundCssClass="FondoAplicacion" TargetControlID="lbClientePop">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="Modificar" Visible="false" />

<asp:Panel ID="panelClientes" runat="server" >
    <asp:Label ID="lbClientePop" runat="server" Style="display: none " ></asp:Label>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCliente" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" >
            <h2> prueba</h2>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelModificarTurno" runat="server"  >

    <asp:Label ID="Lb" runat="server" Style="display: none"></asp:Label>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelModificarTurno" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabelModificar16">Modificar turno</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DropDownEstado" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Estado</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownEstado" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEstado" DataTextField="estado" DataValueField="id"></asp:DropDownList>

                                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceEstado" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MiWeb.Properties.Settings.cs %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Estado]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanelboton" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                            <label for="txtCliente" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Cliente</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliente" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnBuscarCliente" Text="..." OnClick="BtnBuscarCliente_Click" />
                            </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DropdownServicios" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Servicio</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropdownServicios" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceServicios" DataTextField="nombre" DataValueField="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropdownServicios_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

                                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceServicios" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MiWeb.Properties.Settings.cs %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Servicios] WHERE ([activo] = @activo)">
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="true" Name="activo" Type="Boolean" />
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DropDownProfesioanles" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Profesional</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownProfesioanles" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:DropDownList>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ChkPrimeraVez" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Primera vez? </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkPrimeraVez" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="DropDownHsInicio" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Inicio</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownHsInicio" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceHI" DataTextField="hora" DataValueField="id"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceHI" runat="server"  ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MiWeb.Properties.Settings.cs %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [horarios]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </div>
                            <label for="DropDownHsFin" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fin</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListFin" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceFI" DataTextField="hora" DataValueField="id" Enabled="False"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceFi" runat="server"  ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MiWeb.Properties.Settings.cs %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [horarios]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="BtnEliminarTurno" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger" Text="Eliminar turno" OnClick="BtnEliminarTurno_Click"  />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelarMod" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" Text="Cancelar" OnClick="btnCancelarMod_Click"  />
                <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmarMod" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Modificar" OnClick="btnConfirmarMod_Click"  />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>





   protected void btnConfirmarMod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        modificarTurno_ModalPopupExtender.Hide();
    }

   protected void BtnBuscarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

ModalPopupExtender "decides" on its own what z-index to use. Generally it will do the right thing.
The only way I know to assure that your second one will appear on top is to Not use a second ModalPopupExtender, but instead to assign the z-index of the second modal popup explicitly.  I suggest 99999 for the second popup and 99998 for its blanket.  I have seen typical z-index assigned by ModalPopupExtender in ranges of 50000 to 79000 (aprox).